# Duplicate Database entry after refreshing

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to create a database where user inputs their review about a product by using PHP. The function does input the user data into the database but it repeats the last entry every time I refresh the page. How can I get it to stop repeating? I tried header(Location: index.php?reviewed); but it didn't work

```
<?php

function setComments($conn) {

if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];



    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message)
    VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);



}

}


function getComments($conn) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class = 'commentBox'>";
    echo $row['uid']." <br>";
    echo $row['date']." <br> ";
    echo nl2br($row['message']);
    echo "</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: "_I tried header(Location: index.php?reviewed); but it didn't work_" Then you must be doing something wrong there, that's the way to go.

Comment: it still repeats the last entry when I include "header(Location: index.php?reviewed);"

Comment: im not very familiar with a database, this is my first attempt at coding in PHP as well so not sure what I'm doing wrong. However, the video I been following didn't include a header statement and it still didn't repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put `<?php ob_start(); ?>` before using the `header(Location: index.php?reviewed);`. I suggest putting `ob_start()` at line 1

For Example:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<?php function random(){} ?>

<?php header(Location: index.php?reviewed); ?>
```

Comment: so the header will go after both functions or inside a certain one? Im sorry I am not really understanding fully

Comment: `ob_start()` should be put before anything else. The reason why `header(Location: index.php?reviewed);` doesn't work is because you don't have the `ob_start()` before it.